# Make the second instance of a Qt5 application transfer command line arguments to the first instance

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, c++14

I'm making a Qt 5 application that reads the files of a certain type and I want to limit it to one instance. And I want to transfer command line arguments from the 2nd instance to the 1st to make it open a file when user double clicks on that file.

Most information I've found deals with simply disabling running the 2nd instance and not passing data. I've found `QLocalServer` but apparently it is not destroyed when application crashes on GNU/Linux, I've also found `boost::interprocess::message_queue` but it looks like I will have to have a dedicated thread that will read from it. Here's the closest thing I've found: https://github.com/itay-grudev/SingleApplication/ It provides a signal I can listen to but unfortunately doesn't provide an option to pass command line.

What is the best solution? The OSes I care about are GNU/Linux, Mac, Windows and preferably Android.

Comment: You want QtSingleApplication.

Comment: @peppe If you'll provide a step-by-step solution, I will try it and accept if it works. I've only found Qt 4 versions of this before.

Comment: QtSingleApplication has worked in Qt 5 for a while. You can grab it from [here](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt-solutions/qt-solutions.git/) or its improved fork from [here](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt-creator/qt-creator.git/tree/src/shared). Then you just use it in lieu of `Q(Core)Application`, and it gives you signals when another peer connects to your instance, and a method to send data to the running instance. See [here](https://github.com/qtproject/qt-solutions/blob/master/qtsingleapplication/examples/loader/main.cpp#L128) for an example.

Comment: Ok, I got it working. Make an answer and will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've followed @peppe's suggestion and used code in [this example](https://github.com/qtproject/qt-solutions/blob/master/qtsingleapplication/examples/loader/main.cpp#L128) and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Another method is to create and bind a unix domain socket using a predefined socket name or a local TCP socket (on platforms that do not support unix sockets). Bind succeeds only for the first instance of your application. The OS unbinds the socket when the application terminates for any reason. When `bind()` fails that means another instance of the application is already running. The second instance can `connect()` and use this socket to pass its command line arguments to the first instance.